# Django Serving Static Files not loading

Tags: python, django

Setting up a new django application with the following settings:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'kb/media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'kb/static/')
```

Setup a template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HomePage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{% static 'img/girl.png' %}">
    <img src="/media/boy-512.png">
</body>
</html>
```

I assume there's an issue with the settings of how it's supposed to get the static files. In this case the directory for the static image `girl.png` is `kb\kb\static\img\girl.png`

Comment: Are these static files part of an app? If not in what folder in your project are they? And is this in production or development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I can help you, this is my settings.py file and one example in my html template :

I have a project : **MyProject** and one application : **my_project** (inside I have static document > images documents > test.png file)

My **settings.py** file looks like :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "my_project/static"),)
```

And my **HTML template** file with image looks like :

```
<img src="{% static 'images/test.png' %}" />
```

Hopfully to help you

Comment: @Valentin you shouldn't have to use `STATICFILES_DIRS` if the static files are part of an app. If they are in `/appname/static/appname/` they will be picked up automatically. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is only for static files in directories which are not picked up automatically.

Comment: @voodoo-burger Yes it's in a first time, my static document wasn't situated inside my Django application ^^ I just changed the path but I should change that ;)

Comment: @Valentin okay well I downvoted your answer because this is not actually the correct answer to the OP's question. But he seems happy to just copy and paste without actually bothering to understand why this works so no harm done to him I suppose.

Comment: @voodoo-burger Okay ^^ As I said, it's what I do and I'm beginning with Django. So if my answer is pretty good for him or if he solves his problem with part of my answer, it's good ;)

Answer (score 0):

add your project name in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'yourprojectname',]
```